# Change font of the numeration in the image with muptiple subimages

Tags: fonts, graphics, captions, subcaption, changes

So the problem is.
I have an image with 3 subimages (a), (b) and (c).
There is a general caption and each subimage has its own caption.
I have changed the font of all captions, but the numeration (a)-(b)-(c) is written with a wrong font.
How can I correct that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\gratab}[2]{\caption{\sffamily\bfseries\small #1}\label{#2}}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
        \gratab{blahblah1}{fig:A}
     \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
   \gratab{blahblah2}{fig:B}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.33\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
        \gratab{blahblah3}{fig:C}
    \end{subfigure}
    \gratabb{(a) is good while (b) is bad, and (c) is optimal}{fig:ABC}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can change the appearance of the elements (the label, the text etc.) using the capabilities of package `caption`. Please don't do it for every caption individually (though hidden in a macro).

Answer (score 1):

Do not use a self-defined Marco for this. Use the features of the `caption` package. Use `\captionsetup{}` inside a figure if you don't want to set global options.

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{
    labelfont=bf, 
    font={small, sf},
}
```